# Using IB_insync accountvalues() returns none for 'SettledCash'

Tags: string, function, stock, interactive-brokers, ib-insync

I have the following code running to return the specified account value.

```py
def returnAccountValue(tag="SettledCash", currency="USD"):

         accountValueString = ib.accountValues()

                 for a in accountValueString:

                        if a.tag == tag and a.currency == currency:

                                return float(a.value)
```

Unfortunately this returns none, but when I use a different tag such as
'AvailableFunds' it returns the correct value. Has anyone else experienced
this? Are there any issues with my code? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

"SettledCash" is not a valid tag, while "AvailableFunds" is a valid tag.

Since IB_insync is an interface to the TWS Api, it will only be able to retrieve the data available from within the Api itself.

Have a look here, [https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/interfaceIBApi_1_1EWrapper.html#ae15a34084d9f26f279abd0bdeab1b9b5) for a complete list of available data and short descriptions of the tags.

Comment: So how would I go upon getting the balance of settled cash in my account? Is "AvailableFunds" the correct tag?

Comment: "AvailableFunds" is most likely the tag you're looking for.
It does not include any unreal PnL, and tells you 'tells what you have available for trading'.